# Calling a Repast model with a list of model parameters

Tags: agent-based-modeling, repast-simphony

I have an agent-based model which is developed in Repast. To calibrate the model, I need to run the model with a list of parameters. And, use some optimization algorithms to find the best parameter set (minimizing some loss value). I wonder how to do this in Repast Simphony. Apparently, the standard Repast GUI does not support this. I tried batch run, but it seems not what I am looking for either. I could pack the JAVA code as a JAR file, and run it from command line. But how to make the program to take command line arguments in my Repast/JAVA implementation?

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the EMEWS framework (emews.org). The tutorials walk through how to use EMEWS to sweep and optimize Repast (Simphony and HPC) simulations.
The main interface for running the individual models is through the InstanceRunner class. Take a look at Section 8 in the Repast Batch Getting Started Guide: https://repast.github.io/docs/RepastBatchRunsGettingStarted.pdf